# fill a rectangle with 2*1 dominoes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

the problem is to prove that we can only fill a  n*m rectangle with  dominoes only if

n is even  or m is even or both of theme

and if n and m are both odd so it wont be possible to fill the rectangle with dominoes ( 2*1 or 1*2 dominoes ) 
 how to prove this ??

this what i tried :

1 :case n is even and  m is odd 
for n=2 and m=1
we have 1*2=2%2=0 so its true for this case

2-case n is odd and  m is even
for n=2 and m=1
we have 2*1=2%2=0 so its true also for this case

3- case n is even and m is even
for n=2 and m =2 
we have 2*2=4%2=0 also true

now as  general rule we have

we suppose n*m%2=0 ( this mean that we can fill the rectangle with dominos)
if n is odd and m is even 
we have (n+1)*m= (n*m)+m which %2 =0 because even * odd = even and even +even =even

i dont know if what i have done until know is true shall i continue ? i know it must be proved by recurrence

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Color the rectangle as a chessboard. If both $n$ and $m$ are odd there will be more white or black squares, but a domino tile comes exactly one white and one black square.

---

The area being divisible by $2$ doesn't immediately mean that a tiling is possible. In fact you need a further argiment or at least give a construction of the tiling. On the other side the last part of you proof is alright if you want to prove that a tiling is impossible if both sides are odd.

Comment: thank you for the idea

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ and $m$ are both odd area of the rectangle will be odd, but area of dominoes are even. So dominos can never completely fill the rectangle

Comment: yes i see , but how can i prove this by recurrence , ? thank you for you answer